# Brigette Supporter: Does Pokemon GX considered EX?

Tags: deck-building, pokemon

When using **Brigette** supporter card, how many basic GX should I search? Do I need to search only (1) considering it an Ex or (3) considering it as non-EX basic?

I have GX pokemons in my deck and don't know how many of them should I get with that supporter's effect.

[image: Brigette]

Comment: I don't know if there are more comprehensive rules anywhere, but from a quick search I couldn't see any indication that Gx count as Ex, so I think you'd search for 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Pokémon, new game mechanics are introduced from time to time, but this does not mean that they need to interact or be somehow backward-compatible. For most of the time, they are separate.

[**Pokémon-*GX***](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon-GX) is a different card to **Pokémon-*EX*** cards and thus you can find up to 3 **Basic Pokémon** including **Pokémon-*GX*** cards with **Brigette**.

Comment: This thing is awesomesauce! I just hope that they won't do any change in Brigette card's text or rules because of GXs. Hahaha xD

Comment: To add an official source, this is confirmed on the Pokemon webpage at: http://www.pokemon.com/us/strategy/big-changes-in-pokemon-tcg-sunmoon/ "Things that specifically call out Pokémon-EX, such as Carbink's Safeguard Ability, do not apply to Pokémon-GX. That means you can use a Brigette Supporter card to search for three Basic Pokémon-GX and put them onto your Bench!"

Answer (score 1):

Most GX cards are NOT basic, so Brigette is not going to be that helpful to you.  Many GX cards are stage 1 or stage 2.

Comment: Ignoring the premise of the question does not answer it. This is a comment on tactical choice, not an answer.

Comment: Good point - out of the initial 12 GX pokemon with Sun and Moon, only 3 are basic - Snorlax GX, Tauros GX and Lapras GX. There will likely be more basic GX pokemon in future sets.

Comment: It depends on the type of deck. Brigette is a good card for my 2 different decks.